# How to make GDB faster

Tags: c++, c, debugging, gdb

I am debugging complex application with GDB on CentOS 6. It uses custom GCC version (not system one which is obsolete). This application constists of 3 projects: 2 static libraries (one is 50 M in size and another one is 10 M in size in debug build) and executable file that uses code from these 2 libraries, as well as a lot of system shared libraries.
The problem is that GDB is extremelly slow. I understand that this project is big, but Visual Studio 2013 debugs it very quickly, so may be GDB is not correctly set up to work with that big project.
How to make GDB fast when it debugs big projects, including debugging of static libraries code?

Comment: Probably you have large arrays that are dumped at each step. You can reduce the amount of dumped data see `help set print element`.

Comment: Doing *what* in `gdb` is slow?

Comment: The size of archive libraries doesn't matter -- their code is pulled into the main executable, and only *its* size matters. Also, 50MB is small -- we routinely debug 800MB executables.

Comment: When I try to step into, GDB starts to use 100% of one processor core and hangs for a lot of time. I tried to rebuild debug info index, but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 3):

If it is startup time that is the problem, and if you debug more often than you recompile, then you can create a debuginfo index from gdb.  The index speeds up startup and is typically created by distros for this purpose.  Look in the manual for ".gdb_index".